# We have UI problem in Unity IOS build on notched device

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Hello we are developing our game in Unity 2018.2.14f1.

After we made the build, there wasn't any problem on android notched devices but we have a problem on iOS notched devices.

Reds are buttons but greens are button interactive areas.

How can we solve this problem? Have a nice day.

[image: Problem Image2]
[image: Problem Image]

Answer (score 0):

What UI system are you using? If you are using a third party or customed UI system, you should go to check the code about sprite displaying and physics checking. The left border and width of these systems are not aligned. If you are using UGUI maybe the sprite showing up is not really the sprite interacting.

Comment: We use unity gui, box colliders of objects are true position and scale because it works well on notched android.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to canvas scaling for multiple devices. There are two things you can do to achieve this:
(a) Set the resolution aspect manually by adding your iOS's screen size and then scale the canvas manually such as:

[image: Aspect Ratio]

(b) You add "Canvas Scaler" component to your canvas and give your Android device's screen size, since you have mentioned that the buttons are properly aligned in your Android device, by this it will be aligned in your iOS device as well. Or you can just give your iOS device's screen resolution and try with that:

[image: Canvas Scaler]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Tomorrow morning I Will try it and let you know about news.

Comment: We have canvas scaler already on our canvas. Buttons are properly aligned but interactive areas are not aligned properly.